# HTML 5 -- C# Websocket response

Tags: c#, html, tcp, websocket

I'm creating a socket application which is able to receive strings from a websocket within a web page. I have been able to successfully connect the Websocket to my C# program but when ever the webpage sends a string to the program it seems to be encrypted or hashed in some way.

For example if the webpage sends "Test" the program would then output "???9uu?\". I'm obviously missing a step here and I'm not sure what I should searching for to resolve this issue. I'm guessing the string has to be decrypted or put trough a specific function with the TCP key in order to get the actual string?

The code below is the section responsible for receiving the strings from the HTML, (Both "Data" and "MyWriter" output the same string):

```
while (true)    
{ 
    CollectedBytes = new byte[128];
    stream.Read(CollectedBytes, 0, CollectedBytes.Length);
    string Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(CollectedBytes, 0, CollectedBytes.Length);

    Output.Speak("Message: " + Data);

    StringWriter MyWriter = new StringWriter();
    HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Data, MyWriter);

    Output.Speak("Message: " + MyWriter.ToString());

    // The word "Test" should output here
    // But instead "???9uu?\" is.
}
```

I'm assuming that I'm missing a simple step but I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything to help me!! If anyone can give me guidance on what I should do that would be great :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your data's encoding is not ASCII. Have you tried UTF8 or UTF16?

Comment: I'll give that a go now, I believe I tried UTF8 but not UTF16. I'll report back

Comment: I just tried changing the encoding of the data to every available type, they all output a type of encrypted or encoded text just like I had before... I really feel like I'm missing something every simple I just don't know what to search to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to decode data manually without using any WebSocket library? If so, you must know that the payload part of WebSocket frames from clients is **masked**. See [RFC 6455, 5.3. Client-to-Server Masking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.3).